# How to call function on exit

Tags: docker, go, exit

I am running my go project using docker for containers and I would like to call a function when it exits or kill, but what's within the function is not printing:

here is the code I currently have in the main function:

```
sigChan := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(sigChan, os.Interrupt)
    signal.Notify(sigChan, os.Kill)
    defer func() {
        <-sigChan
        fmt.Println("save to disk and clean")
    }()
    sig := <-sigChan
    log.Println("reliable termination", sig)

    s.Shutdown(tc)
```

Comment: You cannot catch SIGKILL, the process is immediately terminated.

Comment: See [SIGTEM SIGKILL callback not getting executed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46648472/5728991).

Comment: You'll have better luck handling container lifecycle hooks at the orchestration layer.

Answer (score 1):

Docker sends *SIGTERM* and *SIGKILL* to container on stop command. Your code should receive these if registered for.

If not receiving still, check if entrypoint is shell form because shell form does not pass the signals, change it to [exec form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

> The shell form prevents any CMD or run command line arguments from
> being used, but has the disadvantage that your ENTRYPOINT will be
> started as a subcommand of /bin/sh -c, which does not pass signals

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer my entry point reads ENTRYPOINT ["./main"] and im still not able to read it on terminal

Comment: Then try registering for syscall.SIGTERM `signal.Notify(sigChan, syscall.SIGTERM)`   
note that docker will wait by default 10 seconds before killing the container.

Comment: tried that it's still not printing, is there anything specific that needs to be added on dockerFiles or docker compose yml maybe?